# How to pass a variable retrieved from service file into the components constructor to the top Decorator?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

can someone please suggest, how can I update the property of a decorator with the value from constructor. And not use an export variable like below, because it always takes this defaulRoute, even though service returns the newRoute.

routeComponent.ts

```
export let routeSelected: Routes = defaultRoute;

@TestRoute({
  route: routeSelected, // -> `this single property needs to have a conditional value passed from service class RouteDB`
})

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.html',
  providers: [RouteDB]
})

export class TestRoute implements OnInit {
  constructor(routeDB: RouteDB) {
    routeSelected = routeDB.routeSelected; // -> it should overwrite and pick this one instead and it does not.
  }
```

service file RouteDB.ts //-> works fine individually

```
@Injectable()
export class RouteDB {
  routeSelected: Routes;

  constructor(private features: FeatureTAPService) {
    this.features.getTapFeature().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(featureOn => {
      return this.routeSelected = featureOn ? NewRoute : defaultRoute;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `return this.routeSelected = featureOn ? NewRoute : defaultRoute;` in this line why you use `return` statement ?

Comment: I removed it, had it by mistake. But it won't impact the issue I'm having for: ```@TestRoute({
  route: routeSelected, // -> `this single property needs to have a conditional value passed from service class RouteDB`
})```

Comment: Basically, you want routeSelected update based on service value ? Or can you explain more why you are using @TestRoute() decorator ? @ShivaniBali

Comment: yes, I want the @TestRoute() decorator to have the updated value from the service class. But It only picks up the global variable I've initialized it with. May I know how can I override the global variable here, because the service class does return the correct value, but the global variable in component is not updating the decorator with correct value.

Comment: okay, trying this way. Will update back in few minutes.

Comment: doesn't work. ```export let routeSelected: Routes = defaultRoute;``` still keeps the default value, even tho ```routeSelected``` is getting updated value from service file.

PS: the detectChanges() method is getting called, but no impact upon the global variable.

Comment: Can you make small demo in stackblitz so that it will be more helpful.

Comment: sure, I've added both files there but they won't run as alot of depdencies would be needed. ```https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbhxfj?file=src/app/TestRoute.component.ts``` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbhxfj?file=src/app/TestRoute.component.ts

Comment: thank you very much for putting in time and effort, my bad If I couldn't elaborate it right. It does get the correct value from the service file. But if you see there's a decorator at the top of  ```component.ts``` file, which I'm trying to update with the new updated value.  Here ```@TestRoute({
  route: routeSelected, // -> `this single property needs to have a conditional value passed from service class RouteDB`
})``` it just takes the global variables value not the updated one in the constructor.

Comment: yes, my applications routing depends upon this decorator. It selects which paths to incorporate. It's kind of existing functionality and my goal is to update this decorators variable conditionally retrieved from the service file. Now the service file does return the correct variable, but the decorator being a global one doesn't pick the value retrieved in constructor. Hence, I had to create a global variable up top so that it picks the variable data. But unfortunately it does't get updated with the value I get from service file.

Comment: I see, I want to handle the routes property of decorator here in the component file. it's the global variable I'm passing into it.  ```export interface TestRoute {
    routes: Routes;
}

export interface Routes {
    temp: string; etc} ```

and the global variable I pass is also of type Routes:

```export let routeSelected: Routes = defaultRoute;
```

Comment: yea the decorator works as per your code. Sorry, but if I've to update the property of decorator, how one would do that?

```
@TestRoute({
  route: routeSelected --- > this one
})
export interface TestRoute { routes: Routes; }
```

Comment: super, I have 2 queries:
1. do we need to declare the decorator twice? like one global and another inside constructor?
2. While putting it inside constructor it says: ```Declaration expected```

Comment: thank you very much, I highly appreciate. I'm trying to use the Behavior Subject as you suggested and to subscribe it in the component instead, because my decorator comes from the backend service file and cannot be updated. It's like packaged library

Comment: Now you have many ways and choose the most right option which is applicable to your need.

Comment: Hello @ShivaniBali `isTestable.call(this, { route: routeSelected });` you need to add this code, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-711apa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts in-side demo at line-number 27 check it our. Now, you can update `route` property based on `routeSelected` too.

Comment: super, let me quickly try it out..

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work, still picks the default value. Is it because the @ isTestable decorator is a backbase model? 
```  export let routeSelected: Routes = defaultRoute; @ isTestable({route: routeSelected})
// inside constructor
isTestable.call(this, { route: routeSelected }); 
```

Comment: In my demo its working fine! see console.log in browser console.

Comment: yeah, I followed it correctly. But still no luck. :/

Comment: In this case now you have to discuss with your backend  team and discuss the way how you can re call decorator or if they provide way to subscribe rxjs in decorator then its better option too.

Comment: dont forgot to share, Which way is working for you ? I also wanted to know which right way will work for you.  :)